c++ for beta distribution
I have the following code to sample from a beta dist
#include <random>
#include <ext/random> // Include the header for __gnu_cxx::beta_distribution

int main() {
     std::cout << "Starting program..." << std::endl;

    try {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        __gnu_cxx::beta_distribution<double> dist(23, 171); // Use __gnu_cxx::beta_distribution

        std::cout << "Generating random value..." << std::endl;
        double random_value = dist(gen); // Assign the result to a variable
        std::cout << "Random value generated: " << random_value << std::endl;

        printf("Random value: %f\n", random_value); // Print the random value
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Ending program..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The process becomes idle for reason that I don't know https://www.programiz.com/online-compiler/0Jei4jG5u7M7f. However if I adjust the parameter to be dist(1, 1) it prints out 0.579891. I wonder what went wrong with my implementation.

I'm certainly no expert but have you considered that the function is just very expensive to calculate given the parameters 23 and 171?

Gee, I wonder why it might work very fast when given the simple values (1, 1) and not so quickly when you give it the much larger values (23, 171)... Maybe it's like why you might be able to easily move two one pound weights (one in each hand), while it would be much more work to move 23 pounds and 171 pounds (which clearly would involve substantially more effort)?

Sorry I should have been more clear. What confuses me is that if it's just being too slow or if there is some other problem(infinite loop etc.) cause the program never seem to be ending.

Why are you using implementation details like stuff in the namespace __gnu_cxx ? Use the documented beta distributions: GNU - the beta distribution

The implementation of __gnu_cxx::beta_distribution contains an infinite loop until it generates __x and __y that add up to less than 1:
result_type __x, __y;
do {
  __x = std::exp(std::log(__aurng()) / __param.alpha());
  __y = std::exp(std::log(__aurng()) / __param.beta());
} while (__x + __y > result_type(1));

With your values of alpha and beta, __x and __y are always around 0.9 so the condition is never true: https://godbolt.org/z/Pshf3b9h4
I couldn't find any documentation for __gnu_cxx::beta_distribution but I'd imagine your values of alpha and beta are simply invalid values and lead to undefined behaviour. I'd recommend not using this class unless you can find documentation of its specification.

Thanks for the answer! Is there a defensive approach that can prevent infinite loops like this from happening? Supposedly we can do a timeout but that would not terminate the infinite loop.

@Adam the best way to do it would be to only use code you understand and have specifications for
